# How to parameterize the interior of a triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, triangles, parametrization

I would like to know how to parameterize a triangle over $[0,1] \times [0,1]$. I actually only care that the mapping is surjective but a bijection is always nice I suppose.

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772828/how-to-parametrize-a-triangle) in which an answer accidentally answers my question but when I check the result it doesn't seem to be correct. As I understand the proposition it states that $(u, v) \mapsto u\cdot A + v\cdot B + (1 - u - v)\cdot C$ where $A, B, C$ are the vertices of the triangle.

For instance take the triangle specified by the vertices $(0,0), (0, 1), (1, 0)$. If we follow though with the computations with $u = 1, v = 1$

$$1.0 \cdot (0,0) + 1.0 \cdot (0, 1) + (1.0 - 1.0 - 1.0)\cdot (1, 0) =$$
$$ (0, 1) - (1, 0) =$$
$$ (-1, 0) $$

which is not a point on the triangle that I mentioned. Did I make a mistake in my calculation? Have I misinterpreted the meaning of vertex here? If I have not made some kind of mistake, be it in calculation or interpretation, then

note: It has been noted that the linked parametrization maps the right triangle to any other triangle *not* the square requested. So is there a mapping of the unit square to the right unit triangle?

Comment: You need all three of $u,\  v,\  1-u-v$ to be nonnegative. $\qquad$

Comment: but then that isn't really a parametrization. How does one make this a parameterization? That is how does one make it so that maps points on the unit square to *only* points on the triangle

Comment: It *is* a parametrization, just over a different domain than the unit square. It is also the standard approach in fields like numerical analysis and computer graphics, so if you want something different it might be wise to talk about why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $(u,v)\mapsto A+u(B-A)+uv(C-B)$ should work, but it is not bijective (all points of the form $(0,v)$ get mapped to the point $A$.

Comment: What about $A=(0,0), B=(1,0), C=(0, 1)$? It seems (0, 1) gets mapped to (-1, 1) if I have done my calculations correctly. But that is not on the triangle.

Comment: My mistake. I actually meant uv instead of (1-u)v. Changed it.

Comment: Can you do this for any simplex? That would knock this answer out of the park for me.

Comment: Also could you explain why this works? It looks pretty perfect to me (because it plays nice with derivatives and isn't piecewise) but I don't know how it works really.

Comment: It is basically a parametrization of a quadrilateral, just with the length of one side equal to zero. For a higher dimenional simplex one could probably do a similar thing, i.e. view the simplex as an n-cube (cuboid?) with some sidelengths equal to zero, but one would have to figure out which sides exactly.

Comment: I like that! I also found a proof of why it works. For simplicity consider the orthogonal case mentioned above in my question (the triangle [0,0;0,1;1,0]). this winds up mapping (x, y) to (x*y, x-x*y). When you add them up you get x. x is in [0, 1] so the sum of dimensions is also in [0, 1] which means we are below the line from (0, 1) to (1, 0). because each variable ranges over [0, 1] we must be in the bounds of the triangle. Now we just need to show a surjection: if you want to cover (x', y') then set x to x' + y' and set y to x'/(x'+y').(x, y) will map to (x, y) thus we have a surjection.

Comment: To generalize to an any triangle requires a bit more work but this is the case that I needed specifically

Answer (score 1):

The parametrization that you found requires $u\ge0$, $v\ge0$, and $u+v\le1$. To handle the case $u+v\ge1$, you can apply the same parameterization but replacing coefficient $u$ with $1-u$ and coefficient $v$ with $ 1-v$ (since in that case $1-u+1-v\le1$, while $1-u$ and $1-v$ continue to be nonnegative). Then the coefficient $1-u-v$ becomes $u+v-1$. This ends up parameterizing the triangle twice over.

Comment: then I just plug in (0, 0) for (u, v) and have the same issue...am I confused here?

Comment: If $u=0$ and $v=0$ you use the original parameterization. The second version applies only if $u+v\ge1$. So your formula has to consider two cases.

Comment: ah so a piecewise surjection. hmm...I was hoping for a nicer solution but that seems reasonable. So basically this splits the unit square along the diagonal and maps the bottom half to itself and the top half to the bottom half.